# Unable to mount XFS volume after reboot - unknown filesystem type 'xfs'

Tags: ubuntu, mount, xfs, ec2

I have an aws ec2 instance that's been running Ubuntu 12.04 for a good long while.  It has attached to it an EBS volume formatted with xfs.    Today after a reboot, I'm unable to mount this volume.  After the reboot, it did not get automatically mounted as per /etc/fstab.   Trying to manually mount it as below, I get the following:

```
mount -t auto /dev/xvdf /usr/local/mnt/media
mount: unknown filesystem type 'xfs'
```

So it appears Ubuntu has forgotten about xfs...  Any hints or ideas as to what I can do to get this volume mounted would be really appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you've lost the `xfs` kernel module somehow. What kernel are you running — official or home-grown? Copy-paste the output of `uname -a` and of `find /lib/modules -name xfs.ko`.

Comment: I have the same problem; the `xfs` module is loaded and `xfs` is listed in /proc/filesystems.